# FPGA able to send data, but unable to receive data. (UART - RS232)

Tags: fpga, embedded, uart, rs232, debugging

I have a DE0-nano FPGA board and I am trying to establish a serial connection with my PC.

I am using the RS232 implementation from here: http://www.fpga4fun.com/SerialInterface.html

I have tested sending from the FPGA, and it worked perfectly. However, when I try to send to the FPGA, it seems to not be working.

Here is my verilog code:

```
module Learning(
    input clk,
    input RxD,
     output LED
);

wire RxD_data_ready;
wire [7:0] RxD_data;
reg [7:0] data;

async_receiver RX(.clk(clk), .RxD(RxD), .RxD_data_ready(RxD_data_ready), .RxD_data(RxD_data));

always @(posedge clk) if(RxD_data_ready) data <= RxD_data;

assign LED = (data == 8'h24);

endmodule
```

Basically I have designed it such that a specific LED on my board turns on while I am sending the hexadecimal value 24. Since I am sending this value at a very high frequency I do expect the LED to remain on for the whole transmission. However, nothing is happening. It stays off.

I already tried the reverse bit option from my rs232 program. Also, using a symmetrical value like 0x55 didn't work.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Just a few random thoughts: could it be a bit-ordering issue (you send MSB first, but read LSB first or vice versa)? What happens if you test with bitpatterns like 0x00, 0xFF, 0x55 or 0xAA?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau yeah I already tried the reverse bit option from my rs232 program. Also, using a symmetrical value like 0x55 didn't work.

Comment: I have added your explanation to the question.

Comment: Are you sure your LED isn't turning on for a few milliseconds then turning off after completion?

Comment: @Zack yes I'm positive. The transmission can last as long as i want and i let it go for a long while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

Turns out the particular RS232 module I'm using works optimally with an input clock of 25MHz. My FPGA main clock is 50MHz, so I simply ran it through a 1 bit divider to obtain a 25MHz clock. Using this as my UART clock worked perfectly.

I also used the 8 LEDs to display the 8 bits of data being received, which helped immensely.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't debug Verilog the way you can with C and a microcontroller, you need to take incremental debugging steps...

- If you just assign LED 1, does the LED turn on and stay on?
- Is data being read at all? Maybe just toggle the LED if *any* character comes in
- Make sure these work and them move on to 0x24

My advice is to take baby steps when debugging, especially with a hardware description language.